# Get parent directory of parent directory

Tags: c#

I have a string relating to a location on a network and I need to get the directory that is 2 up from this location.

The string could be in the format:

```
string networkDir = "\\\\networkLocation\\staff\\users\\username";
```

In which case I would need the `staff` folder and could use the following logic:

```
string parentDir1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(networkDir);
string parentDir2 = Path.GetPathRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(networkDir));
```

However, if the string is in the format:

```
string networkDir = "\\\\networkLocation\\users\\username";
```

I would just need the `networkLocation` part and `parentDir2` returns null.

How can I do this?

Just to clarify: In the case that the root happens to be the directory 2 up from the given folder then this is what I need to return

Comment: FYI: you can write literal strings with an @ prefix to make them more readable/copyable/etc... @"\\networkLocation\users\username". I'm not exactly clear on what you are looking to do from the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("\\\\networkLocation\\test\\test");
if (d.Parent.Parent != null) 
{ 
    string up2 = d.Parent.Parent.ToString(); 
}
else 
{ 
    string up2 = d.Root.ToString().Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)[2]; 
}
```

Is what I was looking for.  Apologies for any confusion caused!

Comment: It's not a good idea to use _strings_ when dealing with path manipulation.  Consider using `DirectoryInfo` instead

Answer (score 24):

You can use the System.IO.DirectoryInfo class:

```
DirectoryInfo networkDir=new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Path\here\now\username");
DirectoryInfo twoLevelsUp=networkDir.Parent.Parent;
```

Comment: This returns null if the string is in the format `\\Path\here\username`

Comment: It will return null if you back up all the way to the root, i.e. C:\ or \\server\share.

Comment: In the case that the root happens to be the directory 2 up from the given folder then this is what i need to return

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar situation.  Looks like you could just call `GetDirectoryName` twice!

```
var root = Path.GetDirectoryName( Path.GetDirectoryName( path ) );
```

Viola!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (I use it in my command lines / batch files all the time).

```
string twolevelsup = Path.Combine("\\\\networkLocation\\staff\\users\\username", "..\\..\\");
```